# Software averaging filter for ADC readings in a boost converter application

Tags: adc, noise, boost

I'm working on a boost converter using a microcontroller (STM32G030), and I need to measure input and voltages of the converter. But, due to switching noise, the ADC readings become noisy and cause the micro to take "undesired" decisions based on the measured voltages. I tried using moving average filter, but it causes the output voltage of the converter to "oscillate" between two values. This is because as soon as the "filtered" output voltage crosses above the set voltage threshold, the duty cycle is decreased (but the response of the filtered output voltage is not too quick), and when the "filtered" output voltage crosses below the set threshold, the duty cycle is increased (but again, the response of the filtered output voltage lags behind, it initially keeps decreasing), this causes the duty cycle being set at a value which results in a voltage which is much larger than the set output voltage.

Can somebody suggest a filtering algorithm (or a different approach to implementing the firmware of the boost converter) which maintains a quick response and filters out noise at the same time?

Comment: Sound like you are trying to counter poor hardware layout with a soft fix. Not usually a good idea.

Comment: As Andy says, or poor control design: one can trigger the ADC such that samples are taken away from switching edges (consistent phase each cycle, ripple aliases to DC), or multiple times per cycle (smaller aliasing residual).

Comment: +1 for tasteful selection of the sampling point

Comment: Synchronous sampling also eliminates any effects of the ripple voltage.

Comment: "as soon as the "filtered" output voltage crosses above the set voltage threshold, the duty cycle is decreased"  This sounds like you're using bang-bang or pure proportional control.  Are you?   Please _edit your question_ with details about your controller, preferably in the \$z\$ domain or as difference equations, but if code then simplify it as much as you can to express just the action of the controller.

Comment: If your sampling is occasionally sweeping across your switching spikes, the only firmware change that will save you is the one that samples the input during a quiet time.  If you can't do that in firmware -- change the hardware.